# Is it true that conductors of electricity are terrible magnets, and vice versa? Why?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Certain metals, like gold, copper, and silver are excellent conductors of electricity, but make terrible magnets. Iron, nickel, and neodymium are excellent magnets but terrible electric conductors.

Does this hold true for all metals, that the better it is at conducting electricity, the worse it is at emitting a magnetic field, and vice versa? Why?

Comment: I'd be hard pressed to call Fe, Nd, and Ni as "terrible" conductors. Sure, not as good as Ag or Cu, but way better than any number of other elements much less compounds. Now, does this have something to do with the band structure? Well, at some level yes. But it is complicated.

Comment: You might look at my answer at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58847/why-is-copper-a-better-conductor-than-iron/80673#80673 and see if that helps some.